# Replaced screen for my laptop, now can't control brightness (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon, backlight

I replaced the broken screen on my laptop (System76 Gazelle 11, rebranded Clevo W60RZ1, running 16.04) with one I ordered from a replacement screen site and I can no longer control the brightness from the keyboard buttons, the battery slider, or even the terminal. I spent all day yesterday trying to update drivers, etc., and somehow ended up making my Cinnamon environment nonfunctional and lost a bunch of dependencies in the process. I have since gotten Cinnamon to reinstall (losing the Icing task manager along the path because it's no longer supported and finding Cobi Windows List instead) but still no luck with the backlight.

I've tried everything I can find by Googling, but nothing has worked. Specifically, 90% of the results go back to either the Brightness Controller, which is a band-aid fix at best that I can't even get to install, or editing the 20-intel.conf file in `usr/share/X11/xorgconf.d/`. I did also get a System76 firmware update in the process and that didn't help either.

I just tried installing brightness controller again and it wants to remove over half of the things on my computer: [Paste](http://justpaste.it/8valc).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I mean, have you tried testing it with a different environment, where it's more likely to work out of the box (e.g. Windows)?

Maybe the new screen uses a different controller/firmware/driver, which is incompatible with that the laptop previously had (and expects).

I haven't yet had to replace a laptop on a screen, but at least on Hackintoshes (which might be a bad example, but I can't think of anything else) you usually have to do quite a bit of patching to get backlight control working, because the controller is simply something else than what the OS expects.